# How can I get rid of the error "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type" when I need float variables in my dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate the pearson correlation between two datasets through a loop, and then I am graphing it using matplotlib. However, I keep getting this error message which I'm not sure how to fix because the data points cannot be rounded to integers to keep the data accurate. I'm somewhat of a new coder so I may be missing something simple.

I'm excluding the parts where I import the dataset and create a graph, since I'm almost positive they are correct. If they are necessary for understanding what I did though, please let me know!
Here is the code where the problems are:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as scipy

# imported datasets here

a1  = ws.variables['A'][:]
b1 = ws.variables['B'][:]
c1 = ws.variables['C'][:]
u = ws.variables['U'][:,:,:] # c vs. a vs. b

a2 = tp.variables['a'][:]
b2 = tp.variables['b'][:]
v = tp.variables['v'][:,:] # a vs. b

u np.ma.masked_invalid(u)
v = np.ma.masked_invalid(v)

tp.close()
ws.close()

ua = np.mean(u,0)

y2 = np.concatenate((a1,a2))

ua = ua[y2,:]
v = v[y2,:]

#the most recent thing I tried; did not change error message
y2 = y2[:].astype(int)

for y2 in range(0,60):
    correlation_coefficient, pearson_cor = scipy.stats.pearsonr(ave_WS,TPalt)
```

I will then use the correlation coefficient to make a graph.

Comment: Not sure if it's the issue, but you have the wrong quote here: `c1 = ws.variables['C’][:]`

Comment: You can probably fix it by not trying to use an array of float values as index into another array.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: there is also a missing `=` sign on this line `u np.ma.masked_invalid(u)`. This code could never work.

Comment: Full error message please!  Indexes do not 'interpolate', so there's no point to using floats.  Indexes select one or several values from an array (or dataset)

Comment: What's that `y2` supposed to be doing?  The itrratiin variable isn't used/?

Comment: Matplotlib is imported but unused.  I suggest removing it from the tags (and the code example).